# Unable to select data from database

Tags: php, angularjs

```js
 //angularjs_DB.php
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hris_iit");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $sql="SELECT idemployee, current_designation,current_salary,previous_designation,previous_salary,reason,effective_date from promotion";
 $result = $con->query($sql);
 
     // output data of each row
  $output="[";
     while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  if($output!="["){$output .=",";}
  $output .='{"idemployee":"' .$row["idemployee"] .'",';
  $output .='"current_designation":"' .$row["current_designation"] .'",';
  $output .='"current_salary":"' .$row["current_salary"] .'",';
  $output .='"previous_designation":"' .$row["previous_designation"] .'"}';
         //echo "<br> id: ". $row['idemployee']. $row['current_designation']. $row['current_salary']. $row['previous_designation'];
  
 }
 $output .="]";
 mysqli_close($con);
 
 echo ($output);
 //return ($output);

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <script src="angular.min.js">
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div data-ng-app="" data-ng-controller="customerController">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><b>idemployee</b></td>
    <td><b>current_designation</b></td>
    <td><b>current_salary</b></td>
    <td><b>previous_designation</b></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{x.idemployee}}</td>
    <td>{{x.current_designation}}</td>
    <td>{{x.current_salary}}</td>
    <td>{{x.previous_designation}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  function customerController($scope,$http){
   $http.get("http://localhost/startup/angularjs_DB.php")
   .success(function(response){$scope.names=response;});
  
  }
 </script>
 <!-- The code above can also be used to fetch data from a database -->
</body>


<html>
```

```
Problem in output of the html code that are not values from Database !!!
Output likes following: 
idemployee  current_designation current_salary  previous_designation
{{x.idemployee}}    {{x.current_designation}}   {{x.current_salary}}    {{x.previous_designation}}
```

Comment: Can you send me the what error it show

Comment: Actually no error occurs. But can not get values from database by the given html code

Comment: can you include the json your php creates? I don't PHP but I'd suggest grabbing an array from the database and serializing that to JSON is 'better'. My guess is that the JSON isn't valid and Angular can't use it. Do you see errors in the browser's console?

Comment: also, unless PHP is super magical you'll need to JSON.parse(response) before you can use it

Comment: I should inform you that, I am beginner of PHP and AngularJS. How could I include JSON in php? I have made array and echo json_encode($output); in the last line of the php code, but cannot get solved.

Comment: not in your example above you don't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a demo that shows how to use the string generated by your PHP http://plnkr.co/edit/p8kDN3Mj1AcmR6ml312H?p=preview

```
myApp.controller('customerController',function ($scope,$http){
        //  $http.get("http://localhost/startup/angularjs_DB.php")
        //  .success(function(response){$scope.names=response;});
        $scope.names = JSON.parse('[{"idemployee": 1}, {"idemployee":2}]')
        });
```

I didn't bother writing out the whole JSON but you can see how it works

---

Also, I don't write PHP so I don't know how to do it, but you don't need to loop over your result set. You should be able to grab the entire set as an associative array and pass it to json_encode

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its not still working. Do I need to change any other portion of the code?

Comment: no error.
Output likes following: 
idemployee  current_designation current_salary  previous_designation
{{x.idemployee}}    {{x.current_designation}}   {{x.current_salary}}    {{x.previous_designation}}

Comment: I've just realised you don't init the app. bear with me while I make a demo

Comment: It would be my pleasure.